# How do I find the taxonomy tag of the current page in DotNetNuke 6?

Tags: c#, webforms, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I am creating a custom module that will find articles on my site based on the page tag used on any page. In order to do this I will need to find the TabId which I have done by simply adding `DotNetNuke.Common;` to the namespace and using `this.TabId` to get the actual TabID.

The trouble I am having is trying to find what taxonomy tag(or tags) being used on the current page.

**Edited**
I tried using [this tutorial](http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/WebDevelopment/CMSPlatforms/DotNetNuke/ListTaxonomyTermsbyPage.aspx) and I was not able to get the list to print out. Several references seem to be missing in the article.

Comment: Did you ever get an solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: I found this bug log which seems to indicated the issue is resolved 7.3.2. Im currently on 8.1 and pageTag no worky still,
https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-5345